# How to specify more then one value for one key in RouteValueDictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, request.querystring, querystringparameter

I need to redirect to a page with multiple values for the same querystring key.
like:

```
?x=abc&x=yz
```

This is a constraint, I can not change how this service accepts his parameters.

How can this be done using the RouteValueDictionary?

It is not possible to add the same key twice

```
myRouteValueDictonary.Add('x','abc');
myRouteValueDictonary.Add('x','yz');
```

Results in an error (of course)

Adding a array of strings did not do it either.

```
 myRouteValueDictonary.Add('x',new string[] {'abc','xy'});
```

Resulted in `?x=System.String%5B%5D` :-)

I am out of ideas.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6048622/1625737

Comment: Found answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295180/create-routevaluedictionary-with-multivalued-keys.